# Install different python version on Anaconda

Tags: python, cmd, package, anaconda, python-3.7

I am needing to install Python 3.7

Tried the command `conda install python=3.7`

I get:
`

```
C:\Users\USER>conda install python 3.7
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - 3.7

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

`
Any idea why this isn't working? I'm able to select the python version in pycharm so not sure what's going on.

Comment: are you trying to have multiple python versions in the same env? Is there a reason for this? Otherwise you can have different envs with different python versions. You can do that by `conda create -n python3.7 python=3.7` and so on.

Comment: Just trying to change the python version in the current environment. Need 3.7 to work with Matlab

Comment: "*Need 3.7 to work with Matlab*" - why so? If the point is to sideload packages into Matlab's Python, you shouldn't be using Anaconda **base** for that. Create a dedicated environment, as suggested.